# Repeating specific columns for unique row values

Tags: c#, datatable

I am relatively new to C#. I will give examples in terms of stock in a supermarket.

I currently have **one table**, which has one row for each unique StoreID/Product combination, that uses this layout:

```
StoreID  Store   Country   Product   In-Stock?  Count  SalePrice
   1     Tesco   UK        Soap      Yes        10     £2.99
   2     Asda    UK        Soap      No         0      £0.00
   3     Aldi    UK        Soap      Yes        15     £2.98
   1     Tesco   UK        Cheese    Yes        10     £4.72
   2     Asda    UK        Cheese    No         0      £0.00
   3     Aldi    UK        Cheese    Yes        15     £3.57
```

I would like to rearrange this table, so that the outcome is displayed as below:

```
                                  Cheese                        Soap            
StoreID  Store  Country  In-Stock? Count  SalePrice  In-Stock? Count  SalePrice
  1      Tesco  UK       Yes       10     £4.72      Yes       10     £2.99    
  2      Asda   UK       No        0      £0.00      No        0      £2.49   
  3      Aldi   UK       Yes       15     £3.57      Yes       15     £2.98
```

You will see that I have just **one row for each unique store** (defined by the storeID) but the three product related **columns are now repeated for each product** (Cheese and Soap).

Comment: Where is this data coming from? (database? web service?) I'd wonder why it was stored with one table per product to begin with.

Comment: Hi Nikki, the data comes from a database. It is possible to display this in one table (see the adjusted example in my question).

Comment: Well, yes, but are there a set number of products? If not, that can be harder and require some fun PIVOT queries (stored proc, more sql than c#) Or, depending on what you're doing, you can do dynamically generated queries to help you group and display the info. Please provide more details on the framework (asp.net, winforms, mvc, etc) and DBMS (sql server, mysql, access) that you are targeting

Comment: The short answer is that this isn't an easy, out of the box thing to do, so providing more details will help target a solution that would work best for you.

Comment: I always have access to the full list of products, so at any one time i know exactly how many products are available and all of the information about those products. Using asp.net and connecting to SQL Server database.

Comment: Right, but you don't want to have to change all your code / queries if someone adds a product, right?

Comment: Is this webforms, or mvc?

Comment: It is webform. And no, I don't want to change everything if someone adds a product.

Comment: Who is consuming the outcome?

Comment: So, the user would have to scroll a horizontal list of many products? I notice you are in the UK and there are accessibility guidelines you may need to meet. This layout will not be printer-friendly.

Comment: This design is at the request of one of our clients - based in Portugal. And unfortunately they won't budge on the layout of the table (though I appreciate it makes much more sense to scroll vertically than horizontally).

Comment: Okay, there's not a lot out of the box to do this, and I assume they don't want to pay for 3rd party like devexpress, but I bet a couple of fun LINQ queries might do for it. Let me see what i come up with

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue I found when attempting to retrieve the desired output was the fact that a datatable cannot have multiple columns with the same name. So here is a very simple outline of how I retrieved the data the correct format:

1. Retrieve list of unique items.
2. For each item, run a copy of the query with the where clause limiting the data to the single item.
3. Assign a unique name to each of the duplicated columns (The "prefix" sent to this method is the unique item name):

   ```
   DataTable GetUniqueColumnNames(DataTable table, string prefix)
   {
       table.Columns["InStore"].ColumnName = prefix + " - In-Stock?";
       table.Columns["Vanda"].ColumnName = prefix + " - Count";
       table.Columns["Cattleya"].ColumnName = prefix + " - Price";

       return table;
   }
   ```
4. Merge each of the item tables (with unique item related columns) using the StoreID as the tables primary key.

This provides the following:

```
StoreID  Store  Country  Cheese-In-Stock?  Cheese-Count  Cheese-Price  Soap-In-Stock? Soap-Count  Soap-Price
  1      Tesco  UK       Yes               10            £4.72         Yes            10           £2.99    
  2      Asda   UK       No                0             £0.00         No             0            £2.49   
  3      Aldi   UK       Yes               15            £3.57         Yes            15           £2.98
```

Admittedly, it isn't as pretty as I might have hoped - but it does the job!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so this is a very simplistic example of how I might start off doing something like this. (you could get very big and robust with it, if you wanted to, but that's beyond the scope here) If you like this general idea, I'd suggest using LINQ to SQL and skip the datatable conversion stuff altogether. **DISCLAIMER:** (*in before try/catch comments or comments telling me why something is a bad idea, use ORM, etc*) this is demo code only to show how to think about solving this problem without any 3rd party components. Production code would have to deal with missing ids, error handling, proper layout and CSS styles, and a bunch more stuff I won't go into.

**Test.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>

       <div runat="server" id="container">

        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code-behind**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public class MyStoreObject
    {
        public int StoreID { get; set; }
        public string StoreName { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Product { get; set; }
        public bool InStock { get; set; }
        public Int16 Count { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected DataTable dtStoreInfo = new DataTable();
        protected List<MyStoreObject> MyStoreObjects = new List<MyStoreObject>();

        //protected
        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dtStoreInfo.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] {
                new DataColumn("StoreID", typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("StoreName", typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("Country", typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("Product", typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("InStock", typeof(bool)),
                new DataColumn("Count", typeof(Int16)),
                new DataColumn("Price", typeof(double))
            });

        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                FillDatasource();
                TransformDataSourceToObjects();                

                // here's all the things
                GridView1.DataSource = MyStoreObjects;
                GridView1.DataBind();

                // we need to break this down into a multi-column layout; the store name, id, and country in one section
                // then additional sections per product that have the prod as the header, the in-stock, count, and price in body
                // you can create whatever controls you need to display this information

                var MyStoreObjects_Stores = MyStoreObjects.Select(x => new { x.StoreID, x.StoreName, x.Country }).Distinct();
                var MyStoreObjects_Products = MyStoreObjects.Select(x => x.Product).Distinct();

                Table displayTable = new Table();
                TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
                TableCell tCell = new TableCell();
                tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
                displayTable.Rows.Add(tRow);

                GridView oGridViewMain = new GridView();
                oGridViewMain.DataSource = MyStoreObjects_Stores;
                oGridViewMain.DataBind();
                tCell.Controls.Add(oGridViewMain);

                foreach (var product in MyStoreObjects_Products)
                {
                    var resultByProd = MyStoreObjects.Where(x => x.Product == product);

                    GridView gvProduct = new GridView();
                    gvProduct.DataSource = resultByProd;
                    gvProduct.DataBind();
                    TableCell tCellProd = new TableCell();
                    tCellProd.Controls.Add(gvProduct);
                    tRow.Cells.Add(tCellProd);
                }

                container.Controls.Add(displayTable);
            }
        }

        private void FillDatasource()
        {
            // assume this comes from a database query eventually, maybe from a dataadapter fill or whatever
            dtStoreInfo.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Tesco", "UK", "Soap", true, 10, 2.99 });
            dtStoreInfo.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "Asda", "UK", "Soap", false, 0, 0.00 });
            dtStoreInfo.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "Aldi", "UK", "Soap", true, 15, 2.98 });
            dtStoreInfo.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Tesco", "UK", "Cheese", true, 10, 4.72 });
            dtStoreInfo.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "Asda", "UK", "Cheese", false, 0, 0.00 });
            dtStoreInfo.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "Aldi", "UK", "Cheese", true, 15, 3.57 });

        }

        private void TransformDataSourceToObjects()
        {
            // this would ideally come from LINQ to SQL or another ORM, presented simplified here for demo only
            foreach (DataRow row in dtStoreInfo.Rows)
            {
                MyStoreObjects.Add(new MyStoreObject()
                {
                    StoreID = (Int32)row["StoreID"],
                    StoreName = (string)row["StoreName"],
                    Country = (string)row["Country"],
                    Product = (string)row["Product"],
                    InStock = (bool)row["InStock"],
                    Count = (Int16)row["Count"],
                    Price = (double)row["Price"]
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nikki. I am going to work on this today, i will let you know how I get on!